# Java floating point number in comma instead of dot

Tags: java, formatting, local

All I have a floating point number in Finnish local. It is like the following:-

```
  String numberString = "1000,30";
  if(numberString.contains(",")){
        numberString = numberString.replaceAll(",",".").trim();    
    }

    try {
        Number number = Double.parseDouble(numberString);
        return number;
    }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
        System.out.printf(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
```

But this number has value 1000.30. I would like the number should I have value 1000,30. How can I have Number with the comma instead of the dot?
This is a basic question it must have been asked earlier. But all I find is in String data type. I don't see any Number data type.

Comment: The format of a floating point is only relevant for parsing and displaying. So when you want to display it, you just need `String.format`. Have a look at it's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)), to see what parameters you must use, to display a float

Comment: Actually, I have to call a third party API that only accepts Number. So I got the output as  1000.30. That api simply call number.toString().

Comment: then the third party API does not support localization

Comment: At this moment no localization supported for third-party API. Otherwise, I won't be asking this question.

Comment: Hint: The correct way to parse your number is `NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("fi", "FI")).parse(numberString).doubleValue()`. Don't replace characters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When seeing your comment that the API accepts only `Number` and that it calls `Number#toString()` on it, then I see only 1 way to enforce the rightful display. By using your own implementation of `Number` and overwriting the way `Object#toString()` works:

```
public class CorrectlyDisplayedDouble extends Number{
    private final Double internal;

    public CorrectlyDisplayedDouble(Double internal){
        this.internal = internal;
    }

    public int intValue(){
        return internal.intValue();
    }

    public long longValue(){
        return internal.longValue();
    }

    public float floatValue(){
        return internal.floatValue();
    }

    public double doubleValue(){
        return internal.doubleValue();
    }

    public String toString(){
        // replaces periods with commas
        return internal.toString().replace(".", ",");
    }
}
```

Which can then be easily created using following snippet, which then also can be passed to your third party API:

```
Number number = new CorrectlyDisplayedDouble(Double.parseDouble(numberString));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my problem. Really cool trick. It must be helpful for many other cases in my application or for others as well.

Comment: hopefully the API gets not changed some day to remove all commas

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger you're completly right, this is a very API version specific approach

Answer (score -1):

Sample Code :

```
String number = "1000500000.574";
double amount = Double.parseDouble(number);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(amount));
```

Comment: A few explanations and pointers to the documentation would be good.

Answer (score -2):

This will help you to understand how Locale exactly works:

```
public double parse(String decimalAsText) {
    NumberFormat decimalFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    decimalAsText = decimalAsText.replace(' ', '\u00a0');
    ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
    Number n = decimalFormat.parse(decimalAsText, pp);
    return n.doubleValue();
}
public String parse(double textAsDecimal) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRENCH);
    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(textAsDecimal);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(bd.scale());
    String s = nf.format(textAsDecimal);
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use DecimalFormat and Locale, for example:

```
DecimalFormat dfFrance = (DecimalFormat)DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
dfFrance.applyPattern("###.00");
Number n = 0;
try {
    n = dfFrance.parse("1000,30");
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(n.doubleValue());
```